# Can't load .dll file (HRESULT 0x80070002)

Tags: c#, java, dll, eclipse-plugin, fuslogvw

Eclipse does look for a .dll file that a plug-in of mine needs to execute. This is the full path of the file:

```
C:\Eclipse\eclipse-sib\eclipse\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\324\1\.cp\jni4net.n.w32.v20-0.8.6.0
```

Trying to open it like this:

```
public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    File f = new File("C:\\Eclipse\\eclipse-sib\\eclipse\\configuration\\org.eclipse.osgi\\bundles\\324\\1\\.cp\\jni4net.n-0.8.6.0.dll");

    System.out.println(f.getName() + " " + f.getAbsolutePath());
  }

}
```

Does work!

```
Output:
jni4net.n-0.8.6.0.dll C:\Eclipse\eclipse-sib\eclipse\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\324\1\.cp\jni4net.n-0.8.6.0.dll
```

But as I run my plug-in as soon as the file gets accessed I receive the following:

[image]

Using `FUSLOGVW.EXE` it says the same:

```
*** Assembly Binder Log Entry  (26.08.2013 @ 13:53:35) ***

The operation failed.
Bind result: hr = 0x80070002. The system cannot find the file specified.

Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\mscorwks.dll
Running under executable  C:\Eclipse\eclipse-sib\eclipse\eclipsec.exe
--- A detailed error log follows. 

LOG: IJW explicit bind. File path:C:\Eclipse\eclipse-sib\eclipse\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\324\1\.cp\jni4net.n-0.8.6.0.dll.
```

Does anybody know what the problem could possibly be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this error might be because missing dependency for "jni4net.n-0.8.6.0.dll".
On Windows I would suggest to use FileMon/ProcessMonitor to check what files/dlls Eclipse tries to load just before that error.

Comment: Look at depends to see if there are any dependencies not explicitly mentioned in documentation. To really see what happens, run procmon.exe from http://live.sysinternals.com to review the actual kernel calls from Eclipse. You may well be surprised where the files are searched for in the process.

Answer (score 0):

End the filename with: jni4net.n.w32.v20-0.8.6.0
Instead of what you used: jni4net.n-0.8.6.0.dll